# Nginx map $status gives allways default value

Tags: nginx

nginx.conf - http block:

```
map $status $loggable {
    ~^[23]  0;
    default 1;
}
```

Can somebody tell me why this is not working for me?
I always get default 1, even when the status code is 200 or 301?

For example, the following map works fine:

```
map $remote_addr $islocal {
    "127.0.0.1" 0;
    "192.168.178.100" 0;        
    default 1;
}
```

The log file shows me that $status gives correct status code.

nginx.conf - http block:

`log_format  main '$loggable $status - [$time_local] - $remote_addr - "$request"';`

webpage.conf - server block:

```
access_log  /share/NGinX/var/log/access.log main if=$loggable;
```

Log file:

```
1 200 - [20/Jan/2019:12:49:38 +0100] - ...
1 301 - [20/Jan/2019:13:04:43 +0100] - ...
1 500 - [20/Jan/2019:13:11:44 +0100] - ...
1 301 - [20/Jan/2019:13:48:05 +0100] - ...
1 500 - [20/Jan/2019:13:48:06 +0100] - ...
1 200 - [20/Jan/2019:13:59:55 +0100] - ...
1 200 - [20/Jan/2019:13:59:58 +0100] - ...
1 404 - [20/Jan/2019:14:28:03 +0100] - ...
```

Comment: This is just a guess - but I think that `if=$loggable` may be evaluated before the status of the request is known.

Comment: Late, but maybe helps someone: you reversed the normal logic in there, default should be 0 or empty string, and anything else should be 1 or any value (nginx evaluates any non 0 or empty string to true! )